# escaped Ambersand in JSF i18n Resource Bundle

Tags: jsf, internationalization

i have something like

```
<s:link view="/member/index.xhtml" value="My&#160;News" propagation="none"/>
<s:link view="/member/index.xhtml" value="#{msg.myText}" propagation="none"/>
```

where the value of myText in the messages.properties is

```
myText=My&#160;News
```

The first line of the example works fine and replaces the text to `"My&nbsp;News"`, but the second that uses a value from the resource bundle escapes the ambersand, too `"My&amp;#160;News"`.

I tried also to use unicode escape sequences for the ambersand and/or hash with `My\u0026\u0023160;News`, `My\u0026#160;News` and `My\u0026nbsp;News` in the properties file without success.

(Used css no-wrap instead of the previous used xml encoding, but would be interested anyway)

Comment: Please use backticks ` to format code in the question so that SO markdown formatter will be prevented from interperting the HTML/XML entities. For example, `&amp;`. Right now there's quite some ambiguity and confusion in the question.

Comment: ah right thx, i modified it accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT - Answer to clarified question**

The first is obviously inline, so interpreter knows that this is safe.
The second one comes from external source (you are using Expression Language) and as such is not safe and need to be escaped. The result of escaping would be as you wrote, basically it will show you the exact value of HTML entity.
This is related to security (XSS for example) and not necessary i18n.

**Previous attempt**

I don't quite know what you are asking for but I believe it is "how to display it?".

Most of the standard JSF controls contain escape attribute that if set to false won't escape the text. Unfortunately it seems that you are using something like SeamTools which does not have this attribute.

Well, in this case there is not much to be done. Unless you could use standard control, maybe you should go and try to actually save your properties file as Unicode (UTF-16 BigEndian in fact) and simply put valid Unicode non-breaking space character. Theoretically that should work; Unicode-encoded properties files are supported in latest version of Java (although I cannot recall if it was Java SE 5 or Java SE 6)...

Comment: No the question is why is the value in the first line converted to `&nbsp;` whereas the seconds is converted to `&amp;#160;`. I thought it should have the same result. (modified the question above)